# Wrong encoding with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: unicode, encoding, character-encoding, html-agility-pack

Im trying to parse http://www.wein-wg.de/wwg/rheinhessen/worms-pfeddersheim/weingut-goldschmidt/ but cant get the correct charset. The website is using iso-8859-1. Somehow all unicode characters are displayed as ? in Visual Studio.

Is there a possibility to transfer it to the right charset in Visual Studio or anywhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```c#
using HtmlAgilityPack;

HtmlDocument doc;
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

private void getPage(string url)
{
    web.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
    doc = web.Load(url);
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
}

getPage("http://www.wein-wg.de/wwg/rheinhessen/worms-pfeddersheim/weingut-goldschmidt/");
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved with:

```c#
HtmlWeb Webget = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
Webget.AutoDetectEncoding = false;
Webget.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

doc_tmp.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
doc_tmp.OptionReadEncoding = true;
doc_tmp.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
doc_tmp.OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

doc_tmp.LoadHtml(tmp.InnerHtml);
doc_tmp.Save(Console.Out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way:

```
 var url = "https://www.elmundo.es/espana/2019/09/19/5d835eedfdddff788e8b45bd.html";
 var web = new HtmlWeb();
 web.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");

 var doc = web.Load(url); //.OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; 

 HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");


 foreach (var node in nodes)
 {

   txt_contenido.AppendText(node.InnerText + "\n" );

 }
```

see you